Как вернуть загрузочный раздел MBR системы Linux, который был удалён?
Ситуация следующая, имеется образ системы linux, но в образе отсутствует загрузочный раздел.
Вопрос заключается в том, как можно восстановить загрузку этой системы учитывая тот факт, что программа testdisk и похожие на неё не помогли решить эту задачу?

В MBR не бывает загрузочных разделов, так что в такой формулировке вопрос не имеет смысла. Если в этом образе есть ядро и initramfs, то ничего не должно помешать загрузить их каким угодно загрузчиком

К сожалению система не стартует сама, мне фактически нужно вернуть загрузочный раздел, я перечитал много инфы, но сути не понял, как именно я могу решить эту задачу

Как минимум для начала разобраться, как конкретно ваш конкретный образ системы ожидает быть загруженным. Это не инфу перечитывать надо, а образ изучать

Ты про grub-install /dev/sda?

В общем сейчас я загружаюсь с supergrub выбирая в меню нужный мне файл загрузки, но я хочу вернуть загрузочный раздел таким какой он был, чтобы при старте машины система загружалась сама как прежде

Нашёл решение, прикрепляю по шагам, как мне это удалось.
Восстановление сломанной загрузки системы.
Инструменты (все инструменты есть в LiveCD Ubuntu):
mkfs.ext4
fdisk
Ubuntu Live CD
chroot
dd


Забрать образ системы через rsync или scp

Создать виртуальную машину в Virt-manager, и добавить в неё виртуальный диск нужного размера (далее этот диск будет использоваться как конечный исправленный образ)

Примонтировать образ системы, который ранее был загружен как отдельный диск

Загрузиться в Live CD Ubuntu для дальнейших операций

Отформатировать ранее созданный диск с помощью mkfs.ext4

С помощью fdisk разметить диск, и создать на нём раздел или разделы

С помощью dd записать ранее загруженный образ сломанной системы на подготовленный диск

Монтировать записанный диск в /mnt:
$ sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt


Монтировать директории для работы chroot:
$ sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
$ sudo mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
$ sudo mount -o bind /run /mnt/run
$ sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys


С помощью chroot починить grub:
$ sudo chroot /mnt
$ sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda # заменить /dev/sda на то устройство, куда хочется установить GRUB

в случае ошибки:
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda —force # (принудительно)

СТОИТ ОТМЕТИТЬ, ЧТО GRUB МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ ВЕРСИИ 2, Т.Е. GRUB2

Выключить виртуальную машину и попробовать загрузиться с диска, на котором проводились работы

Также важно отметить, что при монтировании диска к виртуальной машине следует учитывать выбор - SATA-диск или иной


Надеюсь кому-то это поможет, к сожалению мне стоило это большого количества времени

Обратите внимание, что ни на каком из этих этапов нет никакого «загрузочного раздела MBR», о чём я и писал в самом первом комментарии

я некорректно выразился, но думаю суть понятна
